# How to pass the class type to the function in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a function to determine whether the list contains the specified gpuimage filter type, want to pass a param:`GPUImageSaturationFilter` to function, function uses it to do:

```
public var filters: GPUImageFilterGroup

//filterClass:the specified gpuimage filter type extend GPUImageFilter
public fun getFilter(filterClass:the specified gpuimage filter type):GPUImageFilter {
        //filters.filters is a List<GPUImageFilter>
        filters.filters.forEach {
            if (it is filterClass) {
                 return it
            }
        }
}
```

How to replace the following fun argument? I don't want to use HashMap, Thank you!

```
filterClass:the specified gpuimage filter type
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `filterClass` to be determined at runtime:

```
public fun getFilter(filterClass: KClass<out GPUImageFilter>): GPUImageFilter? {
    //filters.filters is a List<GPUImageFilter>
    return filters.filters.first { filterClass.isInstance(it) }
}
```

(note it has to be nullable because maybe `filters.filters` doesn't contain anything of this type). Which can have a more precise return type

```
public fun <T : GPUImageFilter> getFilter(filterClass: KClass<T>): T? {
    //filters.filters is a List<GPUImageFilter>
    filters.filters.first { filterClass.isInstance(it) } as T?
}
```

To call:

```
getFilter(GPUImageSaturationFilter::class)
```

See [`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html). You can also use [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and

```
getFilter(GPUImageSaturationFilter::class.java)
```

You can also do (assuming you already defined one of the versions with `KClass`, otherwise you can use its definition with `it is T` in place of `filterClass.isInstance(it)`):

```
public inline fun <reified T : GPUImageFilter> getFilter() = getFilter(T::class)

getFilter<GPUImageSaturationFilter>()
```